# Read and Compare cells in a excel file with C++

Tags: c++, excel

I have a project to read an excel file with C++, and then compare the columns to see which are similar, I am really not sure where to start.  I just need a little help on getting started on the right foot.  I am sorry if this was asked before, I did not see it.

Comment: Do they have to be `xls` files, or can you use `csv` files? The latter is much easier. The former requires `COM` interfaces.

Comment: Try searching msdn for help in reading from excel files

Answer (score -1):

You can use different frameworks for such purposes.
I suggest you to check out QT: [qt docs for QAxObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaxobject.html)
Then, you can operate with excel file in this way, for example:

```
QAxObject* excelApp = new QAxObject("Excel.Application");
excelApp->setProperty("Visible", false); 

QAxObject* workBooks = excelApp->querySubObject("WorkBooks"); 
workbooks->dynamicCall("Open (const QString&)", QString("path to .xls file"));

QAxObject* workBooks = excelApp->querySubObject("ActiveWorkBook"); 
QAxObject* worksheets = workBooks->querySubObject("WorkSheets"); 
QAxObject* worksheet = workBooks->querySubObject("Worksheets(int)", 1);
QAxObject* usedrange = worksheet->querySubObject("UsedRange"); 
QAxObject* rows = usedrange->querySubObject("Rows"); 
QAxObject* columns = usedrange->querySubObject("Columns"); 

int rowsStart = usedrange->property("Row").toInt(); 
int rows = rows->property("Count").toInt(); 
int columnsStart = usedrange->property("Column").toInt(); 
int cols = columns->property("Count").toInt(); 


QAxObject * cell;

for (int i(rowsStart); i != rowsStart + rows; ++i) { 
    for (int j(columnsStart); j != columnsStart + cols; ++j) {

    cell = excelApp->querySubObject("Cells(Int, Int)", i, j );
    QVariant val = cell->dynamicCall("value");
    // Do whatever you want with value here.

   } 
}
```